# Reading value of ccount registry on esp8266 returns probably invalid resut

Tags: embedded, esp8266

I'm trying to read the value of ccount register on esp8266. Though the first read after reset seems to be sensible, the rest values seem to be fishy.

Here is a **complete** code snippet I'm using

```
/* Hello World Example

   This example code is in the Public Domain (or CC0 licensed, at your option.)

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, this
   software is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
   CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_spi_flash.h"

static inline uint32_t get_ccount(void)
{
    volatile uint32_t r;
    __asm__ __volatile__("rsr %0,ccount":"=a" (r));

    return r;
}

static void print_ccount()
{
    uint32_t c = get_ccount();

    printf("ccount: %u\n", c);
}


void app_main()
{
    for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
        print_ccount();
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
    printf("Restarting now.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    esp_restart();
}
```

First read after reset is usually something like 659430, 110466 etc, but the rest values is usually recurring '1981' value or something similar. Even after reset, all reads after the first read return '1981' value.

Sometimes the output looks like this:

> �ccount: 110466

I'm afraid that there is some garbage on the stack but I can't figure out what is the cause.

Comment: Without knowing the ESP8266 in detail: Is it possible that `ccount` is reset after each read? That would explain why you get the same value each time, beginning with the second read.

Comment: I checked it in a Reference Manual but there is nothing about clearing this register while reading from it. RM https://0x04.net/~mwk/doc/xtensa.pdf

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question with new information. Down here in the comments it will be overseen. -- Then, does `vTaskDelay()` use the `ccount` and reset it?

Comment: Concerning the first character: Assumed that you use a real serial connection, this depends on the time and level before the first start bit. You might want to insert a little delay (more than 1 bit time) before sending the first character.